# A big line bundle in complex compact manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I look for a reference of the following implication
Let $ X $ be a compact complex manifold,
If :  1) $ \chi (O_X) \neq0 $ 
2) the Universal covering does not contain compact subvariety 
So $ K_X $ is big .
We know that $ K_X $ is big $\implies$ $ K_X $ is nef, when can we have the equivalent?

Comment: $K_X$ big does NOT imply $K_X$ nef, nor in general neither in this case.

Comment: I suspect the OP claims this only for $X$ satisfying 1) and 2). But the question certainly needs to be clarified.

Comment: @abx thanks. But still, I don't immediately see why if $X$ satisfies 1) and 2), then this is true...

Comment: @diverietti: if $X$ is not minimal it contains some rational curve, which lifts to the universal covering.

Comment: @abx what you say it's ok for projective manifolds. But this is merely compact complex. Even in the compact Kähler case "$K_X$ not nef implies presence of rational curves" is not known!

Comment: In any case I really don't understand what the OP would like to know...

Comment: @diverietti: Yes, of course I had the projective case in mind. And I don't understand either...

Comment: @diverietti I think that  if $ K_X $ is not nef, then $ \mathcal {k} (X) = - \infty $ where $ \mathcal {k} (X) $ is the Kodaira dimension

Comment: @Samir, thai is as wrong as possibile, in general! Once again you should write better your original question! What do you have in mind? A projective manifold? Or merely a compact complex one?

Comment: @wnx I was (and am) totally calm! My tone wasn't aggressive, maybe I had to add some emoticon? :) This said, the OPs question lacks a lot of information and has indeed some mistakes in it! It is indeed quite indecipherable. But it's not a big deal, right? I was just trying to push the OPs to reformulate better his question, for his own advantage!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the projective setting the following holds true (this is taken from J. Kollár "Shafarevich maps and automorphic forms", Proposition 13.14.2).

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. If $K_X$ is nef but not big, and $X$ has generically large fundamental group, then $\chi(\mathcal O_X)=0$.

Here, generically large fundamental group roughly means that $\operatorname{Im}\bigl(\pi_1(W)\to\pi_1(X)\bigr)$ is infinite for every positive dimensional subvariety passing through a very general point of $X$. In particular, your hypothesis 2) implies that $X$ has generically large fundamental group, in a strong way.

Thus, if $\chi(\mathcal O_X)\ne 0$, $X$ is projective, and your hypothesis 2) holds true, it follows that $K_X$ must be big and nef.

Observe that (as I wrote in one of the comments) it is nef not because it is big! It is nef because there cannot be rational curves in $X$, as abc remarked in another comment.

I really don't see how Kollár's proof of the proposition above might be transposed to a non projective setting.

**Addendum** (after the comments of Jason Starr and YangMills)**.** There is a result by J. McKernan which confirms a conjecture by J. Starr (you can find a link to that paper in the comment of YangMills below) roughly stating that the conclusions of the bend-and-break still hold in the setting of $\mathbb Q$-factorial proper algebraic spaces. Over $\mathbb C$, a smooth algebraic space is the same as a Moishezon manifold, *i.e.* a complex manifold whose space of meromorphic functions has transcendence degree equal to its dimension.

So, if you know in advance that for some reason your $X$ is a little more than merely a compact complex manifold, namely if it is a compact Moishezon manifold (in this compact case, this is equivalent to be bimeromorphic to a projective manifold), then if $K_X$ is not nef you get some rational curve and hence some compact submanifold of the universal cover of $X$. This is not possible by your assumption 2).

Summing up, your assumption 2) implies that $K_X$ must be nef, unless possibly if $X$ is not bimeromorphic to a projective manifold. Of course if $K_X$ is big then $X$ is bimeromorphic to a projective manifold. But still, even with your assumptions 1)+2), I am not able to prove the bigness of $K_X$ if $X$ is only assume to be compact complex, or even compact Moishezon.

Comment: There is a paper of McKernan about the case of smooth, proper algebraic spaces that are not projective.  I believe that he claims that each of these contains a rational curve.

Comment: Hi Jason! Now that you say this, I have some reminiscence of a conference in Luminy where McKernan gave a talk around this, but I cannot remember the precise statements... I’ll take a look, cheers!

Comment: McKernan's paper is here https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aspm/1540319494 (paywall) and here http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jmckerna/Papers/space.pdf (free)

Comment: @YangMills thanks! I looked at the paper. I'll add something in my answer later or tomorrow! Thanks again to Jason, too!